# find duplicate count in a list

Tags: python, list, linear-search

I came up with this logic to count the duplicate
1 take input for list length
2 take input of list
3 search in list for the values from zero to last index increment the counter.
I am getting error can anyone help to fix it, I know my this not accurate way to do this can someone help me out

```
n = int(input())
l1=[]
for i in range(n):
    l1.append(input())
print(l1)    
count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
count4=0    
for j in range(n):
       if 1 in l1[0,n-1]:
            count1 =count1+1
       elif 2 in l1(0,n-1):   
            count2=count2+1
       elif 3 in l1(0,n-1):
           count3= count3+1
       elif 4 in l1(0,n-1):
            count4=count4+1          
print(count1)
```

input
4
1
1
2
3
4
output should be 2

Comment: You could use the count method : `len(set([i for i in l if l.count(i)>=2]))`

Comment: _"I am getting error can anyone help to fix it"_: Not if you don't tell us what the error is! Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) -- you should [edit] your question to include the _full_ error traceback, which tells us what the error is, and where it happens, so we don't have to guess

Comment: `l1.append(input())` input returns a string, so the `l1` list will only contain strings, so `if 1 in l1[0,n-1]` will never be true.

Comment: @JohnGordon thankyou I failed my test today due to this :( , Is there any optimal way to count duplicates in a list

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I am sorry, I don't use stack overflow much I will keep it in mind next time

Comment: Your stated input makes no sense (to me). If the first input value is 4 then the subsequent inputs will be 1, 1, 2 & 3. The last 4 can't be input. Not sure what you thought *l1[0,n-1]* would achieve apart from a TypeError exception. What should the output be if *l1 = [1,1,2,3,3]* ?

Comment: The problem is that you're checking `if 1 in l1[0,n-1]` where 1 is an integer value.  But you collected the user input as a string, so integer 1 can _never_ be in the input list.

Comment: @JohnGordon You would be right if it wasn't for the TypeError

Comment: @animeshchaudhri The final line in your code is *print(count1)* Does that mean you're only interested in whether (or not) a value of 1 is repeated/duplicated? If that is so, what are the checks for 2, 3 & 4 for (notwithstanding the aforementioned issues)?

Comment: @Cobra the first input is the length of the list, then values of the list

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `set()` to [remove the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) from the original list, then take the length of the original list minus the length of the new set:

```py
s = set(l1)
count = len(l1) - len(s)
```

I don't think this is the optimal way to do it, but it is the shortest and most intuitive way.

Comment: Why isn't this the optimal way to do it? Not that the set doesn't need to be converted back to a list. `len(set(l1))` gives you the number of elements in the set

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I think `set()` performs multiple memory allocations and copy operations in the heap, doesn't it?

Answer (score -2):

There is a pre built function in list to count the elements

```py
data = [1,2,3,4,1,4]
print("Count of 1 =", data.count(1))
print("Count of 2 =", data.count(2))
print("Count of 3 =", data.count(3))
print("Count of 4 =", data.count(4))
```

But if the number of duplicate elements is what is expected then count of all the elements and sort only those greater than 1.

Get all number of elements which are duplicate

```
data = [1,2,3,4,1,4]
print(len([data.count(x) for x in list(set(data)) if data.count(x)>1]))
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants

Comment: `.count` inside a loop is potentially O(n^2). Why not just count everything first, (maybe using a `collections.Counter` and then select duplicates?